# If a computer can be Turing complete with one instruction what is the purpose of having many instructions?

Tags: instruction-set, turing-complete

I understand the concept of a computer being Turing complete ( having a MOV or command or a SUBNEG command and being able to therefore "synthesize" other instructions such as ). If that is true what is the purpose of having 100s of instructions like x86 has for example? Is to increase efficiency?

Comment: Try to program a Turing machine to decode a GIF and get back to me on how much fun it was.

Comment: I mean if it's Turing complete you could compile C for it and run it.

Comment: "Technically a keyboard only needs one button, you could do everything you need through Morse Code. Why do keyboards have so many buttons on them? There's literally over a hundred!"

Comment: @tadman to make things simpler. I can see where this is going..

Comment: So the compiler just takes advantage of these extra instructions for simplicity and efficiency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Equally, any logical circuit can be made using just NANDs. But that doesn't make other components redundant. Crafting a CPU from NAND gates would be monumentally inefficient, even if that CPU performed only one instruction.

An OS or application has a similar level of complexity to a CPU.

You COULD compile it so it just used a single instruction. But you would just end up with the world's most bloated OS.

So, when designing a CPU's instruction set, the choice is a tradeoff between reducing CPU size/expense, which allows more instructions per second as they are simpler, and smaller size means easier cooling (RISC); and increasing the capabilities of the CPU, including instructions that take multiple clock-cycles to complete, but making it larger and more cumbersome to cool (CISC).

This tradeoff is why math co-processors were a thing back in the 486 days. Floating point math could be emulated without the instructions. But it was much, much faster if it had a co-processor designed to do the heavy lifting on those floating point things.

Comment: Just imagine if the CPU had a `WIN` instruction that booted Windows.

Comment: Hardware support for FP instructions is obviously essential for modern CPUs, too, which is why support for x87 was integrated into the CPU core in Pentium, and later support for more efficient SSE / AVX SIMD and scalar FPU instructions was added into the CPU core in later generations.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that a Turing Machine is generally understood to be an abstract concept, not a [physical thing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E3keLeMwfHY). It's the theoretical *minimal* form a computer can take that can still compute anything. Theoretically. Heavy emphasis on theoretically.

An actual Turing machine that did something so simple as decode an MP3 would be outrageously complicated. Programming it would be an utter nightmare as the machine is so insanely limited that even adding two 64-bit numbers together and recording the result in a third location would require an enormous amount of "tape" and a whole heap of "instructions".

When we say something is "Turing Complete" we mean that it can perform generic computation. It's a pretty low bar in all honesty, crazy things like [the Game of Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My8AsV7bA94) and even [CSS](http://my-codeworks.com/blog/2015/css3-proven-to-be-turing-complete) have been shown to be Turing Complete. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to program for them, or take them seriously as a computational platform.

In the early days of computing people would have to type in machine codes by hand. Adding two numbers together and storing the result is often one or two operations at most. Doing it in a Turing machine would require thousands. The complexity makes it utterly impractical on the most basic level.

As a challenge try and write a simple 4-bit adder. Then if you've successfully tackled that, write a 4-bit multiplier. The complexity ramps up exponentially once you move to things like 32 or 64-bit values, and when you try and tackle division or floating point values you're quickly going to drown in the outrageousness of it all.

You don't tell the CPU which transistors to flip when you're typing in machine code, the instructions act as macros to do that for you, but when you're writing Turing Machine code it's up to you to command it how to flip *each and every single bit*.

If you want to learn more about CPU history and design there's a wealth of information out there, and you can even implement your own using [transistor logic](http://www.megaprocessor.com) or an FPGA kit where you can write it out using a higher level design language like [Verilog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog).

The [Intel 4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004) chip was intended for a calculator so the operation codes were largely geared towards that. The subsequent 8008 built on that, and by the time the 8086 rolled around the instruction set had taken on that familiar x86 flavor, albeit a 16-bit version of same.

There's an abstraction spectrum here between defining the behaviour of individual bits (Turing Machine) and some kind of hypothetical CPU with an instruction for every occasion. RISC and CISC designs from the 1980s and 1990s differed in their philosophy here, where RISC generally had fewer instructions, CISC having more, but those differences have largely been erased as RISC gained more features and CISC became more RISC-like for the sake of simplicity.

The Turing Machine is the "absolute zero" in terms of CPU design. If you can come up with something simpler or more reductive you'd probably win a prize.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have actually made an 8 bit computer out of 74xx TTL gates and taken the time to construct each component e.g xor or d flipflop before using the chip that can do that just 2 inputs and an output.